# Custom theme not taking effect (Android)

Tags: android, android-actionbar

In my styles.xml - under values folder:

```
<style name="CustomActionBarTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
    <item name="android:actionOverflowButtonStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="drawerArrowStyle">@style/DrawerArrowStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="DrawerArrowStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.DrawerArrowToggle">
    <item name="spinBars">true</item>
    <item name="color">@android:color/white</item>
</style>

   

<!-- Overflow menu -->
<!-- ActionBar styles -->
<style name="MyActionBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">#2E6154</item>
    <item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
    <item name="android:icon">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:src">@drawable/ic_overflow</item>
    <item name="android:actionButtonStyle">@style/MyActionButtonStyle</item>
    <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/MyTheme.ActionBar.TitleTextStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="MyTheme.ActionBar.TitleTextStyle" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
    <item name="android:textColor">#FFFFFF</item>
</style>

<style name="MyActionButtonStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.ActionButton">
    <item name="android:minWidth">0dip</item>
    <item name="android:paddingLeft">0dip</item>
    <item name="android:paddingRight">0dip</item>
</style>
```

in the manifest file:

```
 <uses-sdk
            android:minSdkVersion="14"
            android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

 <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/CustomActionBarTheme" >
```

I also suspect the culprit to be `parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat"` but not able to find a reference.

However when I run the app on 5.0.1 there is no effect of the style.
I thought I might have to change this in values-14 folder too, but before that I tried to run the app on a 4.0.1 device, no effect. What do I miss here?

I was using the Holo Light theme before and everything was working fine, as soon as I changed theme to AppCompact, the customization seems to be lost. What do I miss here?

### EDIT

if I change the theme to:
`<style name="CustomActionBarTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">`

I get the following:

```
03-20 15:01:34.433: E/AndroidRuntime(9647): Process: com.exa, PID: 9647
03-20 15:01:34.433: E/AndroidRuntime(9647): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.exa/com.exa.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
03-20 15:01:34.433: E/AndroidRuntime(9647):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2298)
03-20 15:01:34.433: E/AndroidRuntime(9647):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
03-20 15:01:34.433: E/AndroidRuntime(9647):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
03-20 15:01:34.433: E/AndroidRuntime(9647):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
03-20 15:01:34.433: E/AndroidRuntime(9647):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
03-20 15:01:34.433: E/AndroidRuntime(9647):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
03-20 15:01:34.433: E/AndroidRuntime(9647):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
03-20 15:01:34.433: E/AndroidRuntime(9647):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
03-20 15:01:34.433: E/AndroidRuntime(9647):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
03-20 15:01:34.433: E/AndroidRuntime(9647):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
03-20 15:01:34.433: E/AndroidRuntime(9647):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
03-20 15:01:34.433: E/AndroidRuntime(9647): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
03-20 15:01:34.433: E/AndroidRuntime(9647):     at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegate.onCreate(ActionBarActivityDelegate.java:152)
03-20 15:01:34.433: E/AndroidRuntime(9647):     at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.onCreate(ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.java:149)
03-20 15:01:34.433: E/AndroidRuntime(9647):     at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.onCreate(ActionBarActivity.java:123)
03-20 15:01:34.433: E/AndroidRuntime(9647):     at com.exa.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:428)
03-20 15:01:34.433: E/AndroidRuntime(9647):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5933)
03-20 15:01:34.433: E/AndroidRuntime(9647):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
03-20 15:01:34.433: E/AndroidRuntime(9647):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2251)
03-20 15:01:34.433: E/AndroidRuntime(9647):     ... 10 more
```

Comment: What is your minSDKVersion?

Comment: `<uses-sdk
            android:minSdkVersion="14"
            android:targetSdkVersion="18" />`

Comment: Why use @style/Theme.AppCompat if you are developing 14 version. Use Theme.Holo.Please follow http://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/styling.html

Comment: I am using the toggle icon on the Navigation drawer for which there is no way other than importing the app-compactv7 library. To do this I have to extend my navdrawer activity from ActionBar activity and extending means I extend the theme of this activity from AppCOmpact themes.

Comment: Yes change all `Theme.AppCompat` to be `Theme.Holo`

Comment: @Xcihnegn please check the Question for edits, I get an error if I change the theme to holo.

Comment: Are you using `ActionBarActivity` for your activity? if so change it back to `Activity`

Comment: Yes I am using ActionBarActivity, it was Activity earlier, but posts here suggest that if I use a Navigation drawer with v7 support I should extend from an ActionBarActivity?

Comment: So if you want to use V7, then change all `Theme.Holo` to be `Theme.AppCompat`. You can not use both in styles as your codes

Answer (score 0):

You have many mistakes in styles, to use appcompact theme you have to do like this:

```
<style name="CustomActionBarTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat">
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
    <item name="actionOverflowButtonStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
    <item name="drawerArrowStyle">@style/DrawerArrowStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="DrawerArrowStyle" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.DrawerArrowToggle">
    <item name="spinBars">true</item>
    <item name="color">..</item>
</style>

<!-- Overflow menu -->
<!-- ActionBar styles -->
<style name="MyActionBar" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar">
    <item name="background">..</item>
    <item name="windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
    <item name="icon">..</item>
    <item name="actionButtonStyle">@style/MyActionButtonStyle</item>
    <item name="titleTextStyle">@style/MyTheme.ActionBar.TitleTextStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="MyTheme.ActionBar.TitleTextStyle" parent="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
    <item name="android:textColor">..</item>
</style>

<style name="MyActionButtonStyle" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionButton">
    <item name="android:minWidth">0dip</item>
    <item name="android:paddingLeft">0dip</item>
    <item name="android:paddingRight">0dip</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Hi Harry, thank you. It took me a while to figure this out. I am finding problems with setting the text color now. I will give your code a try :)